# Verilog program won't read input

Tags: testing, verilog, hamming-code

I've written this program in Verilog, but when I try to simulate it, it only shows XXXX... both on outputs and on input variables. I don't get what I've done wrong...

PS. In the simulation file i give, for example the value `in = 16'b1101100100001111; #20;` .

```
module hamming_decoder(
output reg [10:0] out,
output reg [3:0] error_index,
output reg error,
output reg uncorrectable,
input [16:1] in
);

reg y; // in case "single error", gives the position of the error bit    
reg [1:0] check; // if check[0] = 0 - no error
              // if check[0] = 1 and check[1] = 0 => double error
              // if check[0] = 1 and check[1] = 1 => single error


assign error_index[0] = in[16] ^ in[14] ^ in[12] ^ in[10] ^ in[8] ^ in[6] ^ in[4] ^ in[2];
assign error_index[1] = in[15] ^ in[14] ^ in[11] ^ in[10] ^ in[7] ^ in[6] ^ in[3] ^ in[2];
assign error_index[2] = in[13] ^ in[12] ^ in[11] ^ in[10] ^ in[5] ^ in[4] ^ in[3] ^ in[2];
assign error_index[3] = in[9] ^ in[8] ^ in[7] ^ in[6] ^ in[5] ^ in[4] ^ in[3] ^ in[2];

assign check[1] = in[1] ^ in[2] ^ in[3] ^ in[4] ^ in[5] ^ in[6] ^ in[7] ^ in[8] ^ in[9] ^ in[10] ^ in[11] ^ in[12] ^ in[13] ^ in[14] ^ in[15] ^ in[16]; 

always @(*)
begin
if (error_index[0] != 0 || error_index[1] != 0 || error_index[2] != 0 || error_index[3] != 0)
    begin
        check[0] = 1;
        error = 1;
    end

if (check[0] == 0)
    begin
        error = 0;
        uncorrectable = 0;
        out[0] = in[1];
        out[1] = in[2];
        out[2] = in[3];
        out[3] = in[4];
        out[4] = in[5];
        out[5] = in[6];
        out[6] = in[7];
        out[7] = in[9];
        out[8] = in[10];
        out[9] = in[11];
        out[10] = in[13];
    end
        else if(check[1] == 0)
                begin
                    error = 1;
                    uncorrectable = 1;
                    out[0] = in[3];
                    out[1] = in[5];
                    out[2] = in[6];
                    out[3] = in[7];
                    out[4] = in[9];
                    out[5] = in[10];
                    out[6] = in[11];
                    out[7] = in[12];
                    out[8] = in[13];
                    out[9] = in[14];
                    out[10] = in[15];
                end
            else if (check[1] == 1 && check[0] != 0)
                        begin
                            error = 1;
                            uncorrectable = 0;
                            y = error_index[0] + error_index[1] * 2 + error_index[2] * 4 + error_index[3] * 8;
                            out[0] = in[3];
                            out[1] = in[5];
                            out[2] = in[6];
                            out[3] = in[7];
                            out[4] = in[9];
                            out[5] = in[10];
                            out[6] = in[11];
                            out[7] = in[12];
                            out[8] = in[13];
                            out[9] = in[14];
                            out[10] = in[15];
                            out[y-1] = !out[y-1]; // ?
                        end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue related to testbench port connections. Are you sure about your test bench instantiation?

Also, to provide proper inputs, you need to have a clocking signal for periodic inputs otherwise all your inputs will travel in design at zero simulation time.

This sample `16'b1101100100001111` is shown as single error input data. It shall be great if you show your test bench also.

I've simulated your code and provided a test bench to it. Leaving the logic part, the design seems to be working fine. The testbench is available [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/J98).

**EDIT:**

Yes,your design is a combinational circuit. The conversion from input to output shall occur in zero simulation time. So, as soon as *in* occurs at 100ns, the value of *out* is computed and test ends abruptly. Just add `in = 0` after 20ns delay and viola..!!

I've appended your test in the above EDAPlayground link, just added the above modification. This [PDF](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCkQFjACahUKEwjTg56-jvfIAhXj46YKHS_CAkk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcourses.cs.washington.edu%2Fcourses%2Fcse467%2F08au%2Fpdfs%2Flectures%2F14-Testbenches.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEQR-5KPq9Ij4ZLZXNTfJWZxWn9RA&bvm=bv.106674449,d.dGY&cad=rja) about basics of test bench coding may be useful.

Comment: This is my Verilog Test Fixture file: `timescale 1ns / 1ps

module hamming_decoder_test;

 // Inputs:
 reg [16:1] in;

 // Outputs:
 wire [10:0] out;
 wire [3:0] error_index;
 wire error;
 wire uncorrectable;

 
 hamming_decoder uut (
  .out(out), 
  .error_index(error_index), 
  .error(error), 
  .uncorrectable(uncorrectable), 
  .in(in)
 );

 initial begin
  
  in = 0;
  #100;
  
  in = 16'b1110101110001011;
  
  #20;

 end
      
endmodule

Comment: sorry: here is the file and a print screen of the result shown: http://we.tl/2ty5m8VbGZ